# How to add stringified script tag in express + jade/pug

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I have express using pug as a view. My index.pug has the following:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
      window.__DATA__ = !{payload}
```

where payload is a json object. It has been stringified in the render function of express:

```
res.render('index', {
    payload : JSON.stringify({
       "anExample": "<script></script>"
    })
})
```

When my Json object has `</script>` it terminates my `window.__DATA =` function early due to the ending script tag. How can I prevent this from blowing up my page? Is this a limitation of Pug or Express or the browser?

Comment: Terence, did you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around the solution is to use a stringify library instead of using the provided `JSON.stringify` function.

Specifically I used the npm module `js-stringify` which changes the `<` characters into unicode in addition to stringifying the json. Hence that is then able to be inserted into a a templating engine like Pug. Pug can then unescape it with `!{my_stringified_json}`. Since it unescapes unicode back to its original, the json ends up being `'anExample: '<script></script'>` instead of it's unicode equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to "break up" the string containing the script tags.

Something like this should work:

```
"anExample": "<script></scr" + "ipt>"
```

This way, `</scr" + "ipt>` won't be interpreted as a closing script tag.

Comment: This wasn't a viable solution because it is pretty difficult to regex a json for script tags and split the strings up. Note I am using a nested json so it gets even more annoying to get rid of script tags within a deeply nested json. I will provide an answer for what I did